# First difference of non-stationary - does the prediction accumulate the errors?

Tags: r, time-series, least-squares, stationarity

I am modeling a non-stationary process (I(1) actually), it looks like this:
[image]

I have 146 data points (monthly data). The ideal model in my case should have:

1. Macro-variables sensitivity
2. Predict the balance out-of-sample for 37 months.

I have tried the first difference of the balance, or differences of the logarithms, to make it a stationary process and create the model specification:
[image: another]

I have x and delta x (regressors) for the next 37 period. However, the dependent variable, delta y, is the changes of the cash balance. To get the cash balance level, I need to accumulate the model prediction (delta y) for 37 months. The prediction seems very unreasonable. I think it's because when I accumulate delta y, I am actually accumulating the errors of the prediction.

So my question is, to model the non-stationary curve, taking differences of the dependent variable and making it stationary may not give us long enough prediction, am I correct?

Thanks in advance.